# Window controller Delegate error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, nswindowcontroller, modal-window

I used this code to show window controller window in modal view. I have actions in window controller for buttons in window. And when i click the button the app crashed and get no error message. Am I wrong in setting the delegate ?

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] beginSheet:windowObj.window modalForWindow:self.view.window modalDelegate:windowObj didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
```

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and retry.  We need a stacktrace in order to help...

Comment: I tried. I don't get any exception , it stops in 'return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);' line with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_1386_GPFLT)

Comment: You should be able to trap the root-cause of that exception...

Comment: I think we could use some more code relating to the existence of `windowObj` and `view`

Comment: @trojanfoe No i couldn't. That is the major issue for cant fix it.

Comment: Well please pursue solutions to try and catch the exception at the place that it occurs; as mentioned before we cannot help without a stacktrace.

Comment: @AlexZielenski 
`windowController *windowObj = [[windowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"windowController"];
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] beginSheet:wwindowObj.window modalForWindow:self.view.window modalDelegate:windowObj didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`windowObj` is being deallocated (probably by ARC if you are using it) before the sheet can display the window. You should add a strong property to whatever class you are using for this and set the windowObj to it like so:

```
@property (strong) MyWindowController *windowObj;
...
// Instantiate the window controller
self.windowObj = [[windowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"windowController"];
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] beginSheet:windowObj.window modalForWindow:self.view.window modalDelegate:windowObj didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
```

Comment: The problem is windowObj is being deallocated. No need for `[self.windowObj loadWindow];` I added strong property and it is working. Thank you.

Comment: Usinf `[self.windowObj loadWindow];` intercepts window delegates which leads to another issue. Its better to avoid such coding in this perspective.